# with NODE js, I type in Terminal npm, and it starts showing me the error. And I can't solve it

Tags: node.js

When I write on Visual Studio Code and I want to verify the result with Node.js I write on the Terminal `npm start` it shows me. And I can't solve it. Note that the version for Node 6.14.8. And laptop device:MacBook Air

```
MacBook-Air-alkhas-b-rjayy:new app 19:2 rjayy$ cd my-app
MacBook-Air-alkhas-b-rjayy:my-app rjayy$ npm start

> my-app@0.1.0 start /Users/rjayy/Desktop/react/my-app/src/new app 19:2/my-app
> react-scripts start

sh: react-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/rjayy/.npm/_logs/2021-03-09T17_37_55_559Z-debug.log
MacBook-Air-alkhas-b-rjayy:my-app rjayy$
```

Comment: try running create-react-app again, it is just a missing package possibly. npm install react-scripts might solve it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the necessary libraries.

cd my-app MacBook-Air-alkhas-b-rjayy:my-app

and then

npm install

and then

npm start